# getting attribute value updated by removing special characters using lxml

Tags: python, lxml

Getting ID attribute and updating its value

```
for elem in doc.xpath('//@id',namespaces={'leg':'http://www.lexis-nexis.com/glp/leg'}):
                s = str(elem)
                replaced = re.sub(r'([^a-zA-Z0-9\.\_])','',s)
                elem=replaced
```

I am getting updated value in value replaced but elem is not updated neither the xml in which i am writing this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through elements that have `id` attributes instead, and then update the attribute value, like so :

```
for elem in doc.xpath('//*[@id]', namespaces={'leg':'http://www.lexis-nexis.com/glp/leg'}):
    elem.attrib['id'] = re.sub(r'([^a-zA-Z0-9\.\_])', '', elem.attrib['id'])

# don't forget to write changes back to the disk if necessary
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .I have a question when i was using the xpath //@id than i was getting some object other than of element type ?that object type is different thats why i was having this problem.